# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#

I have this code and it is giving me collection was modified and cannot enumerate anymore, but I wasn't changing the value:

```
public static void AddtoDictionary(string words, Dictionary<int, int> dWords)
{
    if (DCache.ContainsKey(words))
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> _dwordCache = DCache[words];

        //error right here
        foreach (int _key in _dwordCache.Keys)
        {
            int _value = _dwordCache[_key];

            if (dWords.ContainsKey(_key))
            {
                dWords[_key] = (dWords[_key] + _value);
            }
            else
            {
                dWords[_key] = _value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm changing the `dWords` and not changing `_dwordCache`. There are two dictionaries. I can understand that if I was changing `_dwordCache` it will give me that error but the parameter was being changed.

Comment: Are you sure `DCache[words]` isn't returning the *same* dictionary referenced by `dWords`? In other words, even though you have two variables, maybe you only have one dictionary.

Comment: Before the `foreach` loop, execute this code and tell me the result: `var same = Object.ReferenceEquals(_dwordCache, dWords);`

Comment: This line `if (DCache.ContainsKey(words))` is a clear signal. I think you are getting the same dictionary out from the cache

Comment: Yes it was same dictionary. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure DCache[words] element is not modified elsewhere while foreach is running?

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to blast away this error is converting to a different list:

```
foreach (int _key in _dwordCache.Keys.ToList())
```

Make sure you have "using System.Linq;" at the top of your file.

But if you have huge lists, the suggestion above might kill your program, once everytime you call the code, it will create another list again and again.

Then you could be away from enumerators in this case. Try replace your "foreach" by:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _dwordCache.Keys.Count; i++)
{
    var key = _dwordCache.ElementAt(i);
}
```

Comment: The for statement is the way you would handle it in 90% of other cases but it would not work with a Dictionary, it does not implement `this[int i]` (well it does, but not in the way you are wanting to use it, it is really `this[Tkey i]` and in this question `i` just happens to be an `int`)

Comment: The .ToList() suggestion works.
But yeah, the second suggestion is missing something:
for (int i = 0; i < _dwordCache.Keys.Count; i++)

var key = _dwordCache.ElementAt(i);